# How to change the device partition name of the HDD in ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu

I recently re-installed ubuntu 16.04. The OS is installed on SSD. My HDD is 2TB. By default, the HDD is mounted as `/media/user/Storage'.

My previous installation was `/mnt/sda1'. I forgot how I changed the partition label before.

How can I change the the label from `/media/<user>/Storage` to `/mnt/sda1`? I use to refer this disk by the later name.

Comment: Might be useful for you: https://askubuntu.com/a/1228270/212930

Answer (score 0):

You can add an entry to the harddrive to /etc/fstab to mount the drive you want to /mnt/sda1 if you like.

http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/fstab.5.html